# filter function- how to pass foreign key objects attribute as Keyword

Tags: python, django, filter

I am currently implementing a searching function in Django and plan to use the filter related functions. After reading some doc on django docs, it seems to me that keyword can just be varchar type, in the example below- 'name' filed

```
inner_qs = Blog.objects.filter(name__icontains='Cheddar')
```

Question is if this Blog Table has a foreign key filed called writer ,then

```
inner_qs = Blog.objects.filter(writer.name__icontains='John')
```

is not allowed, showing Syntax Error,Keyword cannot be an expression. But I really want to put certain fields of the foreign key as the search keyword(e.g. writer.name), is there any way to do so? Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that you need filter by name of the writer and writer is a foreign key in Blog table,you can use:

```
inner_qs = Blog.objects.filter(writer__name__icontains='John')
```

Mentioned in Django [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).